# how to retrieve the output value in python/driver of a geometry nodes attribut?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I have a GN node tree with an output value as a float.

[image]

Blender tells me the path to it, which is great. And i got...if i execute it...an "x" ...umpf.

Hoped for a value. How do i get the value?

Comment: Linkage: [Accessing Geometry Nodes mesh data from Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/285066/60486), [Find object instances with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/295347/60486), Blender 4: [blf module: How to draw text in the center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/313554/3), Blender 3.6: [Convert curve to mesh with specified resolution via API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/289573/60486), and using a driver: [Control shape keys with drivers to the speed of rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/294220/60486)

Comment: Generally useful search phrase: [\[geometry-nodes\] \[python\]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes+python)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: but you are aware of the fact, that the question was asked 2022 and you add links from 2023? Makes less sense for me....

Comment: why? It seems to you posting a link is some kind of a reprimand *"you should have known about this because we already wrote about it before"*, whereas I treat them as signposts: we're here, look at the directions to ontological neighbors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to refer to the object attributes, so if the attribute is a vector you can do:

```
obj = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()).data

obj.attributes[0].data[0].vector
```

You might need to adjust the indexes for your attributes.

Comment: Hi! Is there a systematic way of chasing this kind of information down, or is it just something you have to know?, and is there a way of guaranteeing the index? e.g finding index for name?

Comment: Hi. This is somewhat explained here:
<https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/accessing-custom-attributes-created-in-geometry-nodes/>

Comment: Thank you! Good source :)