# Export Geometry Node Raycast Data to Text

Tags: python, mesh, node-editor, geometry-nodes, export

I'm trying to export the XYZ values from Raycast Geometry Nodes to a txt or csv. The output socket *Hit Position*, I know is a vector, but I can't access the coordinates of every hit position. How do I go about this issue?

[image: Raycast GeoNode]

This is the closest I get to achieve the data I need:

```
print(bpy.data.node_groups["Lidar"].nodes["Raycast"].outputs[1])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Geometry Nodes mesh data from Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285066/accessing-geometry-nodes-mesh-data-from-python) In your particular case: set position to the Hit Position, then in Python read the positions of vertices of the evaluated data.

Comment: is the issue that you are only getting one value instead of a vector or is it that you are only getting one vector, when you want one for each point?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady helped a lot, but i need every vertice position, with this one all i have is the number of vertices, not the position:

from bpy import context as C
dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
ev = C.object.evaluated_get(dg)
print("Evaluated Verts:", len(C.object.evaluated_get(dg).data.vertices))

that's what i've tried, can i get the positions of every vertice? thanks for the help

Comment: @shmuel i want one for each point, is that possible?

Comment: @leocfranz each vertex has `co` attribute with a position vector. So e.g. `print(*(v.co for v in C.object.evaluated_get(dg).data.vertices), sep="\n")`

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you so much, it worked, you saved my day!!

Comment: @leocfranz I was gonna say that you'd probably need a for-loop or something like that to go through all the vertices, but seems like Markus already said it.