# I would like to save my amount of instances generated to an ID, so that I can use it later for training purposes

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a random amount of instances appear. I would like to count these and connect it to a seed, such that I have a number for each ID. I have tried all I know, but can´t get it to work!

`bpy.data.node_groups['GeoColony'].nodes['Domain Size'].outputs['Instance Count'].default_value` Doesn´t work.

[image]

Comment: `default_value` is specifically a user input, not output. See: [Accessing Geometry Nodes mesh data from Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/285067/60486), Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks, I am still pretty new to the Blender API, but from your links, I still don´t see how I would output it.
I can hover my mouse over the instance count output and see the correct number, but how do I access it?

Comment: I found a way to do it with a Python script

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XqBHYr5