# How to read the value through Python from Geometry Nodes Output Node

Tags: scripting, node-editor, export, geometry

When the socket is not connected to other nodes, the script can be read into its variable. Everything is fine.

```
MyObjName = bpy.data.node_groups["MyGNStrings"].nodes["Group output"].inputs[1].default_value
```

The value `object_test` is written in variable `MyObjName`:
[image]

But when I connect this socket to other sockets, its value is no longer readable by the script:

[image]

For each animation frame, I need to get my own object index, which will be contained in this socket.

Comment: It depends on the exact domain/type, but see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249956/how-to-retrieve-the-output-value-in-python-driver-of-a-geometry-nodes-attribut.

Comment: More examples: [Accessing Geometry Nodes mesh data from Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/285066/60486), [Find object instances with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/295347/60486), Blender 4: [blf module: How to draw text in the center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/313554/3), Blender 3.6: [Convert curve to mesh with specified resolution via API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/289573/60486), and using a driver: [Control shape keys with drivers to the speed of rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/294220/60486)

Comment: Generally useful search phrase: [\[geometry-nodes\] \[python\]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes+python)

Answer (score 0):

Have you or anyone tried to get the value via identifier? (I tested the code below for Group Input in Blender 4.1 ). Edit: Unfortunately,
for Group Output it gives errors for me. Edit2: It works if you assign some value before you read the value!

```
    import bpy

    in_input_id = bpy.data.node_groups["MyGNStrings"].nodes["Group Input"].inputs["InputObjectName"].identifier #this works 

    value1 = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['GeometryNodes'][in_input_id]  #or whatever the object
    print("input_value=", value1)

    out_input_id = bpy.data.node_groups["MyGNStrings"].nodes["Group Ouput"].inputs["OutputObjectName"].identifier #this get the identifier but not the value for below
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['GeometryNodes'][out_input_id] = "test_string"

    value2 = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers['GeometryNodes'][out_input_id]  #or whatever the object
    print("output_value=", value2)  #KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key "Socket_16" not found' (if you not assign some value to it!)
```