# Find object instances with python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

When using geometry nodes I can see my object has instances

[image]

How can I access `position`, `rotation` etc of all of them through python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
from bpy import context as C
dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
ev = C.object.evaluated_get(dg)
instances = (i for i in dg.object_instances if i.instance_object == ev)

for i in instances:
    location, rotation_quat, scale = i.matrix_world.decompose()
    rotation_euler = rotation_quat.to_euler()
    print(f"{location=}\n{rotation_quat=}\n{rotation_euler=}\n{scale=}\n\n")
```

This should list those properties of instances of the active object.