# How to access geonodes instance position/rotation from python script?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, instances

[image: Geonodes instance data and python window]

I'm trying to access a list of positions, rotations, and scale for instanced geometry (and ideally the name as well) instanced by geonodes for an export script. The instances are NOT realized, and  for this at least I just need the transform data.

But I can't find out how to access the instance data, such as what appears in the Spreadsheet windows, from Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object instances with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295347/find-object-instances-with-python) You can also add a temporary geonodes tree to output any data you want: [Convert curve to mesh with specified resolution via API](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289622/60486)

Comment: Yes, thank you. This worked perfectly for me. I did search for other questions but didn't see the duplicates.