# How to access geometry nodes output value to use as a driver?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, drivers

This is my setup:

[image]

[image]

I want to use the 'x' output as a driver for the mesh line endpoint.

I think [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249956/how-to-retrieve-the-output-value-in-python-driver-of-a-geometry-nodes-attribut) outlines what I'm supposed to do, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to use scripts.

I don't want this question to be closed because the alternative solution that everyone is pointing me towards doesn't answer the question, it just provides a completely different way of achieving what I asked for.

Comment: A better workflow is explained here: [Passing GeoNodes attribute to Shader frame offset](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265282/60486), and here's an answer of mine using this workflow [Control shape keys with drivers to the speed of rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294231/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The first method that you mentioned doesn't work if the single-vertex vertex group is affected by a geometry nodes modifier.

Comment: I think you don't understand these methods, to avoid confusion, create a separate object, with only a single vertex, and use this object to read data from your original object and affect its single vertex by that data.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I tried some experiments and it seems that the method works, but if I connect some other geometry data using 'join geometry' node it resets the empty's position.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Screenshots of the problem: https://imgur.com/a/JE1uDns

Comment: Perhaps the vertex group is not preserved upon joining. This is why it's best to delegate a separate object to transfering the values to empties.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yeah, I did just that. My object contains many moving parts whose positions are set in geometry nodes so I didn't want to separate them into individual objects.

Comment: All you really need is a single "bridge" object containing multiple vertices for multiple empties, so it doesn't create a lot of mess.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I'll look into it. Thank you for your time!